# NTFS permissions using groups does NOT work (Win 2012)

Tags: permissions, file-permissions

My problem is very simple.
Assigning file\folder permissions to individual users in my domain work just fine. 
However if I try to assign permissions to custom groups I created or even the Administrators and\or Domain Admins groups, the users in those groups still can NOT delete\modify any files inside the folders. I'm really starting to pull my hair out on this one.
Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you verified after logging out/in with the specified user?

Comment: Yes, about a hundred times.

One thing I forgot to mention is that these are files that were copied from another server although in the same domain.

Comment: does this activity involve shares, if so what are the share permissions?

Comment: No, no shares.
Just NTFS.

Comment: so these directories exist on the users local workstation?

Comment: It's a server..

Comment: And the users rdp into the server and access these files local to the server?

Comment: RDP is through a VPN but why should it matter? :)

Comment: rdp and vpn doesn't matter in thise case was just trying to understand your configuration.

Comment: This must be some new security feature of server 2012...

Comment: Just verifying:  The server is a domain member?

Comment: When asking questions about NTFS permissions it is a good idea, to post the result of the following commands: 'icacls C:\foobar' where c:\foobar is the directory with problem. Also log on as the user in question and run 'whoami /all' and post both results in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem only occurs with `BUILTIN\Administrators` or `DOMAIN\Domain Admins`, you are likely running up against UAC, which does not specify the builtin admin groups on your login token for medium integrity and low integrity processes (technically, it specifies that they are Deny-Only).  UAC would not, however, affect custom groups.

To rule out UAC being involved, run `explorer.exe` with administrator permissions.  See [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/58933/how-do-i-run-the-windows-7-explorer-shell-with-administrator-privileges-by-defau) for an example of how to do so.

Beyond that, you probably have some hangup in your ACL.  Try dumping it with ICACLS, as @PeterHandorf suggested, and posting the results here.  Things to look for would be:

- Deny entries (which take precedence over allow)
- [Apply to containers only / objects only](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776140%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- Inheritance blocked containers (`Allow inheritable permissions from parent to propagate to this object` unchecked)
- Share permissions

I highly recommend using the [Effective Permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758822%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) tab to rule out any typos, but beware as it may produce misleading results if `Apply To` is set incorrectly.

Also, depending on how the files were copied, they may have brought along unwanted ACLs.  The `Replace all existing inheritable permissions on all descendants with inheritable permissions from this object` option may be helpful.

Comment: They seem to have modified UAC on Server 2012.
Creating a folder and giving permissions only to Domain Admins just dont cut it as a pop up is raised. However, doing the same on 2008 did NOT give out this issue.